# Is there a terminal emulator for Mac OS X that supports binding Ctrl+(Shift)+Tab?

Tags: terminal

I want to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to `\033[27;5;9~` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to `\033[27;6;9~`. Unless I am missing something, the default Mac OS X terminal emulator will not let you bind these key sequences to custom escape sequences like it does with the "F" keys (<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc.) and most other keys.

Is there another terminal emulator I can use on Mac OS X that does support rebinding those keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  There is a product called [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/).  The best part is that it's [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software)

One of the features of iTerm2 is that you can remap any of the keys including the ones you asked about.  For instance, I remapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to send the text `"blah"` it it worked perfectly.

[image]

After hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it sends the keystroke:

[image]

Comment: I just installed iTerm2 and was able to remap Ctrl+(Shift)+Tab to the desired escape sequences. Thanks!

Comment: related not sure if you have any idea https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339647/tmux-control-shift-tab-iterm2  I am not sure if my issue is with the configuration files for tmux or with with iTerm2 Send vs Send to hex vs send something else