# tmux: Control + Shift + Tab & iTerm2

Tags: macos, tmux

How do enable <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> for tmux in iTerm2 for macOS?

This question may be better suited for Unix & Linux Stack Exchange or Super User, except the configuration is somewhat macOS specific.

Right now I can't seem to figure out how to get the the `\033[27;5;9~` send using hex code but it appears to do nothing.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470001/bind-ctrltab-and-ctrlshifttab-in-tmux and related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229155/is-there-a-terminal-emulator-for-mac-os-x-that-supports-binding-ctrlshifttab

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If not, I can provide you with the configurations I use for tmux and iTerm.